# asp.net page will not accept code changes

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I am a little rusty in .net.  I have an old site that I haven't touched in maybe 8 years.  I need to make a minor change to one of the .vb files.  Rather than looking for the visual studio project, I logged into the site and adjusted what I needed in the .VB using notepad.  But the changes don't seem to take effect.

I seem to remember a directive somewhere to tell the site to rebuild, or perhaps not.  Can someone point me to the proper procedure?

Thanks!

Comment: You are not even supposed to have .vb files there. Is this an ashx handler or something?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of site. Since the vb files ARE on the web site?

Then in most cases, you can edit the file, and save it. Based on the datetime of the file, then the site should automatic re-compile for you.

It is possible that the site was deployed as a asp.net web site "application", but then during the publish process then all of the source code files are removed, and would not appear in the sites folder.

Thus, so far, with the information you provided, then yes, you should simply be able to just change the source code. If you have use of IIS manager, then I would try re-starting the site.